# React Native View below Flatlist is flickering

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a view below `flatlist`. I want the view to be always at bottom of screen and it is wrapped  inside `KeyboardAvoidingView`. Check video for more details

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eeMfpH3AV7AqLNqAhlhQX5JmOQSRLbtp/view?usp=sharing

As soon as I comment my `FlatList` code then the bottom view does not flicker.
Below is my code

```
<View>
<FlatList ..../>
<KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      >
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.bottomViewStyle}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image source={CAMERA_CHAT_ICON} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.textAreaViewStyle}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Start Typing..."
              placeholderTextColor="#9b9b9b"
              style={styles.textInputStyle}
            />
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image source={CHAT_SEND_ICON} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

All components including the `FlatList` component should be wrapped inside the `KeyboardAvoidingView`. Also, `SafeAreaView`s should be placed at the root of the screen because it provides padding for SafeAreas.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}>
    <SafeAreaView>
         <FlatList ... />
    
         <View>
             <TextInput ... />
         </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

See https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview and https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview for more examples.